# Generalising a finding in Kaluza-Klein theory to extra spatial dimensions in super string theory a correct method?

Tags: string-theory, cosmological-constant, kaluza-klein, warp-drives, casimir-effect

As a disclaimer I am an A-level student.
I have been doing a research project in which I am looking at manipulating space-time through the ideas provided by superstring theories. I stumbled upon the article [**"The warp drive: A new approach"** by Richard K Obousy and Gerald Cleaver](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.1649.pdf) and was wondering.

**Is the generalisation of the vacuum energy contribution from the Casimir effect in extra-dimensions valid for superstring theories as it was derived from Kaluza-Klein theories?**

I am aware that string theory's extra-dimensions where founded on Kaluza-Klein but am not sure if this is theoretically or mathematically valid.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific about what you want to know - yes, there are Casimir-like effects in general string theory, what exactly do you want to know about that?

Comment: In the paper a generalisation is made for calculating the vacuum energy attributed by the caismir effect in higher dimensions derived from Kaluza-Klein modes ( no clue what those are, I assumes different modes in the GR-EM unified field in KK?) And was wondering if this would hold true in superstring theory?

Answer (score 0):

The paper you link to **The warp drive: A new approach**  is at least  8 years old  and contains this reference:

> Warp drives have not been the sole interest of theoretical physicists as was demonstrated by the formation of the NASA Breakthrough Propulsion Program and the British Aerospace Project Greenglow, both of whose purpose was to investigate and expand on these ideas re-garding exotic field propulsion.

Both of these programs have since been abandoned, read into that what you will regarding their results or validity.

> Is the generalisation of the vacuum energy contribution from the Casimir effect in extra-dimensions valid for superstring theories as it was derived from Kaluza-Klein theories?

The [Kaluza Klein Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory) mentions the fact that it was an early theory postulating a compactified 5th dimension, but I think, as I am no expert, that it would be a stretch to take from this that string theory was derived from it. It also makes no mention of the Casimir Force.

The Wikipedia article [History of String Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_string_theory)  makes no mention of the KK theory.

Again, I would stress I am basically 99 percent ignorant regarding   string theory and that Wikipedia is by no means the definitive source on these topics.

Comment: Personally, I believe the attempts of NASA's with the White-Juday interferometer were verging on fraudulent. It has been shown, if rather approximatetly, that their apparatus could not detect any warp field distortion caused by their apparent source would be undetectable even by an interferometer the size of LIGO. I am unaware of any work done by Project Greenglow but know that it did exist.

Comment: Anyway this is not my concern as my project is accessing future possibilities, perhaps not even human. And on the matter of Kaluza-Klein theory and string theory it is my understanding that Kaluza's original work on compactifying dimensions was applied to bosonic string theory and that lead me to believe that a generalising to superstring theory would be valid. As apart from altering the number of dimensions and different possible manifolds I am unaware of any changes with the way the extra dimensions work.  Anyway thank you for your contribution!